# Recurrence function's runtime

Tags: big-o, recurrence

```
int foo(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)
        sum += foo(n-1);
    return sum;
}
```

I am learning Big O notation recently.
Could someone give me an idea about how to determine this recurrence function's runtime by using big-O notation and how to present the runtime of this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So think about what happens if you run a foo(n) for a big n. The sum then consists of n times a call to foo(n-1). In the next level of the recursion tree we have foo(n-1) and again we call n(-1) times foo(n-1-1) but for each of the n foo(n-1) branches of our tree. We know that the tree has the height of n as we have to go until foo(n-n). So at every recursion step you turn one instance of foo into O(n) instances of foo(n-1).

I am not certain if I should reveal the answer as it seems like an exercise but it seems quit obvious, just draw a few levels of the recursion tree and your find your answer.

Comment: Suppose I assume that n = 3, is that the recursion tree which you mentioned? http://imgur.com/a/lusID

Comment: No, but close. Think about the for loop, the recursive call sum += foo(n-1) is not depending on the loop variable i. So on each node in the tree we branch n times but each leaf is called with n-1. http://imgur.com/a/K9g8z

Comment: Thanks, I got it. What you explain is very easy to understand.